# Route all traffic via OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, chrome-os

I'm using ChromeOS with `openvpn` binary to connect to the OpenVPN server, at the same time only traffic that has to be routed to the internal network, routes to it; the general traffic routes as usual.

How can I route all the traffic to VPN? As I'm using ChromeOS, the best solution for me will be configuring `*.ovpn` file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route or iptables. I think similar question was already asked:
[OpenVPN not default gateway for all traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/648118/openvpn-not-default-gateway-for-all-traffic).